# When ANZ bank replaces a lost or damaged ATM card, will the new card be a duplicate or an entirely new card?

Tags: australia, debit-card, atm

My bank here in Australia is currently ANZ bank.

If I ask them to replace a damaged or lost card, will the new card be an exact duplicate or is a brand new card issues?

Specifically, will the new card have the same expiry date as the damaged card or will it be a new card with the full usable date range of the old card with thus a new expiry date well in the future?

Comment: Just call them and ask. There's no extra charge for asking questions.

Comment: Probably a whole new date range unless you lost the card very soon after you got it, but best to check with the bank itself.

Answer (score 4):

This can be best answered by your bank. There is no prescribed norm.

Generally the Card number is retained, but the expiry date and CVV is new. There are times when the card number is changed if they upgrade or for safety issue a different series.

Answer (score 1):

I will say that when I say my card is damaged I do get the same card.  But your bank may vary.